# Setting Joomla input

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput

I'm using

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
```

to get an array of the input from a page.

I then use:

```
$foo = $jinput->get('jform', '', 'raw');
```

I can then 
    echo $foo['formFieldName']
which prints out the correct value

I then want to change the value to something else

```
 $foo['formFieldName'] = "newValue";
```

But when I get the array again it doesn't change the value.

I'm guessing that there is some sort of setter that needs to be used but I can't get anything to work. Can anyone point me to an example that might work.

edit

I should have put full code.  I did put the value back into the original array:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$foo = $jinput->get('jform', '', 'raw');

echo $foo['formFieldName'];

$foo['formFieldName'] = "newValue";

$foo = $jinput->set('jform', $foo);

$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;

$foo['formFieldName'] = "newValue";

echo "<br>revised foo ".$foo['formFieldName'];

exit;
```

This does show the change in name but after this the system still seems to put in the previous value - like it's held by a global variable or similar.

I'm guessing that it's how I've put it into the code sequence.

Comment: Are you abandoning your prior question?  This feels like a diplicate of that one.

Comment: no this is a separate thing i'm trying to do - I'd still like to solve the other question if anyone is able to help.

Comment: You are setting the value in the forked array. So if you use the `get` method again, it will return the original value. Try using JInput 'set'

Comment: @user don't you mean to read and echo the newly updated `$jinput` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use input's `set()` method to set input values.

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$foo = $input->get('jform', array(), 'array');
$foo['formFieldName'] = 'newValue';
$input->set('jform', $foo);
```